# Under what conditions does MySQL skip rows?

Tags: mysql

I'm reading a data.csv file into MySQL via the LOAD SQL command. My SQL code goes like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/DATA FILES/foo.csv' INTO TABLE foo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This works fine, but out of the 366,000 odd lines, it skips 138 of them. There are no duplicate entries or anything, it just skips them out of the blue. When I try to manually input the row into the table, it works fine. But I can't identify all 138 of the lines, so I'm wondering how exactly to pinpoint the possible reasons mySQL would skip these lines of data.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `show warnings` after the import. it will give you more info

Comment: Same inserting values may larger than respective table column size

Comment: @pala_, it's odd, because the last part of the SQL report says 221,220 warnings (I have some formatting issues, this is normal), but when I try to SHOW WARNINGS it only returns the first 64 warnings. :/

Comment: @NaveenRamawat, I'm sorry, I didn't quite catch that. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: I meant , Some of your csv value which you want to insert in table is might larger than the column size in which you want to insert. in that case insertions may skip.

Comment: But when I tried moving an erroneous row out into an individual CSV file on its own, I could port that in directly... :/

Comment: The first 64 warnings are probably for one problem.  Fix it.  Run it again.  Eventually you will get to some of the 138 missing lines.  You may find character set issues?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.